# Increase kivy scrollview window size with increase widget entries

Tags: python, scrollview, kivy

I have the following code that produces a scrollview of row entries.

```
import ...

class DigestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        s = ScrollView()
        b = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=[1, 5])
        header = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        header1 = Label(text='#', size_hint=[.35, 1])
        header2 = Label(text='header', size_hint=[6, 1])
        checkAll = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        header3 = Label(text='Check All')
        header4 = CheckBox()
        checkAll.add_widget(header3)
        checkAll.add_widget(header4)
        header.add_widget(header1)
        header.add_widget(header2)
        header.add_widget(checkAll)
        b.add_widget(header)
        for i in range(100):
            b1 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
            n = Label(text=str(i+1), size_hint=[.35, 1])
            l = Button(text='> test header 01 02 03 04 050000000000000000000000000000000000', size_hint=[6, 1])
            c = CheckBox()
            b1.add_widget(n)
            b1.add_widget(l)
            b1.add_widget(c)
            b.add_widget(b1)
        s.add_widget(b)
        return(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DigestApp().run()
```

Which produces the folowing output (which scrolls to view all 100 rows):

[image]

This looks great with only 100 rows (for i in range(100)), but when I try to add 1000 rows, i get the following result.

[image]

It should be noted that the scroll function is working, but the display is obviously not desirable.

It seems as though even though my scroll view works as expected with 100 rows, it doesnt properly scale to larger numbers. This is necessary as I may need a window with tens of thousands of rows.

What parameter am I neglecting that accounts for this scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ScrollView to properly scroll through the BoxLayout's content, `b`'s `size_hint_y`should be `None` and its height should be updated as contents are added. For example, define `b` as:

```
b = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint_y=None, height=0)
```

And inside the loop, update its height according to the height of the contents being added:

```
for i in range(100):
    b1 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', size_hint_y=None, height=40)
    (...)
    # Update b height
    b.height += b1.height

s.add_widget(b)
return(s)
```

Defining `b1` with the specific height of 40 is optional but it gives you control on the size of each column. You may leave it with the default value or change to the height that's best for you.

By the way, I find this sort of things easier to control in the kv language, where you could simply write:

```
<b@BoxLayout:>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: sum(x.height for x in self.children)
    (...)
```

And the height of `b` would automatically update with the height of its contents.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the scroller size? It is very small and is too difficult to click on.

Comment: Yes, there is a bar_width attribute and some other that you can use to customize it. http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html